# Cisco 3650 and wifi hotspot

Tags: vlan, ieee-802.11, cisco-catalyst

I have to connect wifi hotspots on cisco catalyst ports of cisco 3650.
The wifi controller is connected on 2 ports, because it delivers 2 wifi vlans (6 and 40).
The hotspots must receive an IP from the DHCP controller on VLAN 40 (untag) and deliver this VLAN to end devices, and also deliver the VLAN 6, which has his own DHCP.

I configured isolated vlans on the 3650 but have problems.
For hotspots, I configured trunk ports which delvers VLAN6 tagged and native VLAN40 untagged, but the hotspots only enable end devices to connect to VLAN6, and don't get an IP from VLAN 40.

**SW3650**

```
vlan 50
name MGMT
ip addresse 192.168.50.10 255.255.255.0
vlan 40
name WIFI-SSID1
vlan 6 
name WIFI-SSID2
int gi1/1/1
switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,6,50
switchport trunk native vlan 40
description TO OTHER 3650
int gi1/0/1
description TO WIFI SSID1 ON WF CONTROLLER
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan 40
int gi1/0/2
description TO WIFI SSID2 ON WF CONTROLLER
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan 6
int gi1/0/10
description TO HOTSPOT
switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk native vlan 40
switchport trunk allowed vlan 6
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the configuration of your WLC and of the 3650.  Use the preformatted { } option.  It's impossible to tell where you may have gone wrong, and just guessing is off-topic here.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I edited the topic. Regards.

Comment: Is it possible to reopen this topic please ? I have no other technical information to communicate (as I don't have control on the WLC, which is managed by the WF provider), and the hotspots are Ubiquiti Unify branded.

Comment: Change your int gi 1/0/10 to `switchport trunk allowed vlan 6,40`.

Comment: For equipment to be on topic here, the manufacturer must offer paid support.  Sadly, Ubiquity does not.  Since you don't manage the controller or access points (not hot spots), there's not much you can do.  I suggest you contact your wireless provider for assistance.

Comment: I did. They said it was a question of Cisco configuration...
Moreover, in case I have to plug other hotspots on another 3650 switch, do I have to put VLAN40 native on the trunk between the 2 3650 switches ?

Comment: Ron, It seems that what you did me to do is functional !
Thank you a lot !

Comment: Well. It works a half. The hotspot have an IP with the DHCP WLC on VLAN 40, but end devices don't have acces to this VLAN SSID. The SSID on VLAN 6 works like a charm.

Comment: That depends on the WLC configuration.  It doesn't matter which VLAN is native on the trunk (or no VLAN is native) as long as both sides match.

Comment: As far as I know, the WLC sends VLAN40 untagged, and VLAN6 tagged. So the port has to deliver those VLANs as hotspots expect to receive them.

Comment: VLANs are tagged per port, so VLAN 40 can be tagged on one port but untagged on another.

Comment: I'm searching for something like this, but on Catalyst:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/smb/switches/cisco-small-business-200-series-smart-switches/smb80-vlan-configuration-on-the-200-300-series-managed-switches.html
The switch port on which the hotspot is connected must deliver untagged vlan 40 and tagged vlan 6

Comment: The switch configuration you have matches that.  Perhaps the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what was th issue.
I had to put native VLAN to all trunks between switches concerned.

Comment: You only need to use a native (untagged) VLAN towards the WLC if you can't get it to accept tagged VLANs. No need to run it untagged between switches.